# Zsh script will not set environment variables

Tags: unix, terminal, environment-variables, zsh

I want to write a script that will take user input using flags/switches and then set ENV variables from this data.

The file is named 'set_env.zsh'.

```
!#/bin/zsh
while getopts eilt option
do
  case "${option}"
  in
  e) ENVIRON=${OPTARG};;
  i) ID=${OPTARG};;
  l) LOGIN=${OPTARG};;
  t) TOKEN=${OPTARG};;
  esac
  echo $option
done

if [ $#ENVIRON -gt 0 ];then
  export PRINTER_ENV=$ENVIRON
  echo $PRINTER_ENV

elif [ $#ID -gt 0 ];then
  export PRINTER_ID=$ID
  echo $PRINTER_ID

elif [ $#LOGIN -gt 0 ];then
  export PRINTER_EMAIL=$LOGIN
  echo $PRINTER_EMAIL

elif [ $#PRINTER_TOKEN -gt 0 ];then
  export PRINTER_TOKEN=$TOKEN
  echo $PRINTER_TOKEN
fi
```

To execute the script:

```
source set_env.sh -e DEVELOPMENT -i printer_01 -l my_email@email.com -t my_tokens
```

When I check the ENV variables using `printenv` none have been set.

However, when I run the same script and just put a `export TEST=test` inside it as the first actual line of code to be executed, then run the `printenv` after, the script successfully saves the ENV variables.

Any insight on the matter would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `bash` or `zsh`? You say `bash` in the title, use `#!/bin/zsh` (you have a typo, by the way) as your shebang, and have both tags; but they are completely different shells.

Comment: Also, options are only considered to take arguments if they are followed by `:`; that should be `getopts e:i:l:t:`.

Comment: Run `set -x` before `source`ing your script to trace its execution; that way you can see exactly which `export` commands it actually runs. (BTW, at least in bash, `$#PRINTER_TOKEN` treats `$#` as the thing to expand, and then just suffixes the literal string `PRINTER_TOKEN` to its result; maybe you meant `${#PRINTER_TOKEN}`? The curly brackets are not optional).

Comment: ...please tag *either* bash or zsh, not both. They're distinct shells, and not compatible with each other. (And name your script with `.bash` if it's meant to be compatible with bash, or `.zsh` if it's meant to be compatible with zsh -- `.sh` should be used for scripts that are sourced only if those scripts are written and verified to work with *all* POSIX-family shells... a family zsh isn't even in, unless it's running in compatibility mode).

Comment: `!#/bin/zsh` will not do what you expect; what you meant is `#!/bin/zsh`. And it has no effect if the line is not the first in the file or the script is sourced.

Comment: ...the parts of this code I'm describing as not compatible with bash are, btw, not compatible with `sh` either -- making them doubly inappropriate to use in any file whose extension is `.sh`.

Comment: I see that this has been edited to remove references to bash. Even in zsh, using `set -x` to enable tracing will work, and is very likely to provide useful clues (if not an outright answer) as to what's going on.

Comment: I've edited my post accordingly. Thanks for the comments. I think there is some info on this message thread that could be useful to other newbie programmers like myself, so whoever downvoted my post please consider reverting the downvote or I will be forced to delete this post and this entire message thread.

Comment: You get a lot more positive reputation from an upvote than you lose from a downvote, so I'd advise against sweating them. As long as more than 20% of folks who read this question (over the long haul) think it's valuable, you'll come out ahead.

Answer (score 2):

Your `getopts` string doesn't allow for option-arguments.

Change it from:

```
while getopts elit option
```

to:

```
while getopts e:l:i:t option
```

...to tell `getopts` that option-arguments are expected after each of `-e`, `-l`, `-i` or `-t`. Otherwise, getopts exits the loop (by returning a value of false) the first time it sees a non-option (like, in your example, the string `DEVELOPMENT`) in the argument list.

---

Also, to improve compatibility with shells other than zsh, consider changing:

```
# This is zsh-only
if [ $#FOO -gt 0 ]; then
```

...to...

```
# This works on all POSIX-family shells, and also some non-POSIX shells like zsh
if [ -n "$FOO" ]; then
```